# Touch input not recognized

Tags: android

I have modified an existing Android launcher that causes a selected group of apps to show at any section of the phone screen based on where the user touched.  Imagine a group of apps that follow the user's touch.  I wanted to limit this range in order to account for gestures and live wallpaper touch areas.

I did so by blocking off a section of the overall height shown below.

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int y = (int) ev.getY();
        int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        if (pieView.inListMode() && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
            return true;
        } else if ((ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (y<(height/8) || (y>height*7/8))) {
            return onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        try {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // Never saw this happen on any of my devices but had two reports
            // from Google so it's probably better to catch and ignore this
            // exception than letting the launcher crash.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This area no longer shows the the app list when touching in these regions.  The problem now is that touch inputs from the live wallpaper (KLWP) in this region are not working.  It's as though touch input in these regions are not being recognized, are there any glaring issues with using return onTouchEvent(ev) for this?  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.  I'm still very new to coding in Android.

**Update:** I was able to fix this issue by enabling 'Use direct touch' in KLWP.